# How to call correctly base class constructor from inherited class in Delphi Phrism?

Tags: class, constructor, compiler-errors, delphi-prism, inherited

I have two classes - base class and inherited class as follows.

**Base Class:**

```
TAlarm = class(System.Object)
private:
protected:
public:
    constructor (tag:TTagname);
end;
```

**inherited class:**

```
  TAlarmMsg = class(TAlarm)
  public
    constructor (aname:string);
    method GetAlarmMsg:string; override;
    method SendMsg(msg:string);
  end;
```

**constructors:**

```
constructor TAlarm(tag:TTagname);
begin
  Tagname := tag;
end;

constructor TAlarmMsg(aname:string);
begin
  inherited TAlarm(aname); <========Here is my problem.
  name := aname.ToCharArray;
end;
```

No matter what or how I call or play around with inherited constructor, I keep getting the following error messages when I compile the source file.

**- Self cannot be accessed before the inherited constructor has finished. And/OR
 - Cannot find appropriate constructor in base class so manual call to inherited is required**

By the way, I have spent good half a day researching on this issue and have found good information online. Nothing helps so far. I even found the webpage that directly talks about constructors on Delphi Prism Wikipedia ( http://prismwiki.embarcadero.com/en/Constructors ).

So, how would you do it correctly? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement
`inherited constructor(aName);`
should do it.

Comment: @ CK, aName is a string not array of char and that's why it had problem. I simply corrected the offending line as follow: inherited constructor(aName.ToCharArray); It works. Thanks,

Comment: instruction `inherited;` alone at the beginning of the sub-class constructor seems to be ok

Comment: Yep that works too. Although not when I answered this